# Split dates range column into months - Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe , with a start-date column, an end-date column and 2 columns of values:

```
Start date  end date        A    B
01.01.2020  30.06.2020      2    3
01.01.2020  31.12.2020      3    1
01.04.2020  30.04.2020      6    2
01.01.2021  31.12.2021      2    3
01.07.2020  31.12.2020      8    2
01.01.2020  31.12.2023      1    2
.......
```

I would like to split each raw into monthly ranges, replicating the value in column A, and splitting the value in column B depending on the number of days of each month:

```
Start date  end date        A    B
01.01.2020  31.01.2020      2    (3/182)*31
01.02.2020  29.02.2020      2    (3/182)*29
01.03.2020  31.03.2020      2    (3/182)*31
01.04.2020  30.04.2020      2    (3/182)*30
01.05.2020  31.05.2020      2    (3/182)*31
01.06.2020  30.06.2020      2    (3/182)*30
01.01.2020  31.01.2020      3    (1/366)*31
01.02.2020  29.02.2020      3    (1/366)*29
.......
```

where 182 and 366 are the number of days of each date range (e.g. from 01.01.2020 to 30.06.2020).
I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you divide by 182 in the row2?

Comment: it is written below, because I have to divide B values proportionally to the number of days in each month. So I divide B by the total number of days in the date range (182 = days from 01.01.2020 to 30.06.2020, it is a leap year, so february has 29 days), then I multiply by number of days in each month